# Eclipse "quick type hierarchy" as diagram

Tags: java, eclipse

How to get Eclipse to display the equivalent of "quick type hierarchy" as a diagram?

Comment: What kind of diagram are you talking about?  And exactly what information do you want in the diagram?

Comment: I'd like something that complements this view http://eclipseone.files.wordpress.com/2009/12/quick-type-hierarchy.jpg with something like this http://i.imgur.com/AO3wz.png, in a tooltip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Eclipse plug-in does something similar to the Q:

```
ObjectAid UML Explorer
@ http://www.objectaid.com/update
- ObjectAid Class Diagram
- ObjectAid Sequence Diagram
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, this kind of functionality is not included in any of the standard Eclipse downloads.

If you mean as a UML class diagram (or similar) then you would need an Eclipse plugin that can reverse engineer diagrams from source code and do a half-decent job of layout.  Start by looking at the UML tools in the Eclipse Marketplace.  (Sorry, I can't make any recommendations.)

Comment: I already use Papyrus (http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/papyrus/) for UML. I just meant: interactive help, quick diagram in a floating tooltip. Especially: which classes implement the current interface and the like.